# How to attached pdf in order email?

Tags: magento-1.9, pdf, send-mail

I need to attached pdf file inside mail, while sending order email to the customer.

Any one please tell me flow for that ?

Answer (score 1):

Install [this](https://store.fooman.co.nz/magento-extension-email-attachments.html) extension will help you.

Set **Attach Order As Pdf** to **Yes** in

system > configuration > Sales Emails

Comment: Your link now redirects to homepage.  Can you please update?  I do see the extension is called "email-attachments-by-fooman"